# PHP CRUD application: supply array indexes dynamically

Tags: php, ajax, mysqli, crud

I am making an Employees CRUD application using mysqli.

I have an Employees HTML table displaying users from a data base table called "users", like below (the template file is users.php):

[image: All Employees are listed in this table]

I wanted to click the view user link at the right of the first user (that eye icon) to display his profile. What method should I use, considering I have a `$get_users` array containing all the users data so that:

```
<pre><?php print_r ($get_users); ?></pre>
```

displays

```
Array
(
  [0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [first_name] => Alex
        [last_name] => Smith
        [email] => alex.smith@gmail.com
        [telefon] => 0743127315
        [oras] => London
        [adresa] => 5th Shaftesbury Ave.
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 5
        [first_name] => Doe
        [last_name] => John
        [email] => jdoe80@yahoo.com
        [telefon] => 0743127315
        [oras] => London
        [adresa] => 5th King's Road
    )

)
```

and of course `<?php print ($get_users[0]['first_name']); ?>`

displays first user's first name - Alex. But I cant just hardcode a **view_user.php** page for every user in the data base.

My view_user.php file (template) contains this HTML table:

```
<table id="single_user" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
        <td>First name</td>
            <td><?php echo $get_users[0]['first_name']; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Last name</td>
            <td><?php echo $get_users[0]['last_name']; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Email</td>
            <td><a href="mailto:<?php echo $get_users[0]['email']; ?>"><?php echo $get_users[0]['email']; ?></a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Phone</td>
            <td><?php echo $get_users[0]['telefon']; ?></td>
        </tr>   
        <tr>
            <td>City</td>
            <td><?php echo $get_users[0]['oras']; ?></td>
        </tr>   
        <tr>
            <td>Address</td>
            <td><?php echo $get_users[0]['adresa']; ?></td>
        </tr>   
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I need that `$get_users` array indexes generated dynamically: `$get_users[index]` where index takes values from 0 to the total number of users minus one.

So what is the fastest and safest way to do that? (AJAX?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can:

/view_user.php?id=3

where:

```
$user_id = $_GET['id'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `user_id` = " . (int)$user_id;
```

EDIT:

Well you should be able to use $_GET['id'] just fine in your function.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `user_id` = " . (int)$_GET['id'];
```

But keep in mind that this approach is very wrong for many reasons.

You should start reading about and use a framework like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/docs/5.3/) which provides all the necessary tools needed to make your life easier and just to be able to concentrate on your business logic, instead of reinventing the wheel.

Comment: my $sql's are in a finctions.php file. This file is only included in all my tempaltes. Whare should your code above live? Thank you!

Comment: I am not trying to reinvent the wheel. I an new to PHP an MySql and trying hard to make a working application.

Comment: I understand. Just try to add the $_GET variable inside the query like I showed you and add an extra ?id=(whatever id you need) in the browser or ajax request. And do read and learn about franeworks. Most of the time they are life savers.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what do you want, if you want it to load dynamically or in another page. If you want in another page you can use something like the first answer:

- Add a link on your view button: /user.php?id=# (the user id filled automatically)
- Create a function in your functions.php to get only one user `get_user($id)` where you write your SQL and return all your data.
- Call the get_users function and set it to an array to have all your info `$user = get_user($_GET["id"])` and use it wherever you need.

If you want ajax you load this content either in a lightbox or append a div to your content. I usually use `jquery-confirm.js` to load content in a lightbox. You can set it to have dinamycally content and return your `user.php` data. You can use the same file as in the non-ajax version. For the title you need another file if you want to keep it simple.
Short example:

```
$.dialog({
    title: /user-title.php?id=#,
    content: /user.php?id=#,
});
```

It has a More info on the plugin here: https://craftpip.github.io/jquery-confirm/